# Iterate Previous Lines after find a pattern

Tags: python, parsing

I am searching for a pattern and then if I find that pattern(which can be multiples in a single file) then i want to iterate backwords and capture another pattern and pick the 1st instance.

For Example, if content of the file is as below:

```
SetSearchExpr("This is the Search Spec 1");
...
ExecuteQuery (ForwardOnly);
var Rec2=FirstRecord();
if(Rec2!=null);
{
```

Then the Expected Output:
ExecuteQuery Search Spec = "This is the Search Spec 1"

I have figured out by below to check if ExecuteQuery is present, but unable to get the logic to iterate back, my code as below:

```
import sys
import os
file = open("Sample_code.txt", 'r')
for line in file:
        if "ExecuteQuery (" in line:
            #if found then check previous lines for another pattern
```

If anyone help me with a steer then it would be of great help.

Comment: Instead of iterating through the file, use `readlines()` to put all the lines in a list. Then you can iterate backwards using list indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to go backwards. Just save the `SetSearchExpr()` line in a variable and use that when you find `ExecuteQuery()`

```
for line in file:
    if 'SetSearchExpr(' in line:
        search_line = line
    elif 'ExecuteQuery (' in line:
        m = re.match(r'SetSearchExpr\((".*")\)', search_line)
        search_spec = m.group(1)
        print(f'ExecuteQuery Search Spec = {search_spec}')
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow not able to execute this 
import sys
import os
import re
file = open("Sample_Applet.sif", 'r')

for line in file:
    if 'SetSearchExpr(' in line:
        search_line = line
        # print("Ashish")
    elif 'ExecuteQuery(' in line:
        if search_line in locals():
            m = re.match(r'SetSearchExpr\((".*")\)', search_line)
            search_spec = m.group(1)
            print(f'ExecuteQuery Search Spec = {search_spec}')

Tried to put a defensive check as well but it is getting end up in the below error:
NameError: name 'search_line' is not defined

Comment: Please ignore i have got the issue.